# Do punches and vulnerabilities have a type when using Animal Man?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

Do Punches/Vulnerabilities have a type when using Animal Man (when using 3 or more card types, +2 power)?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! Be sure to check out our [tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. It looks like you are asking two questions, but this site works by asking one at a time. I've edited the question to focus on just one. If you'd like the other question answered, feel free to [ask it as a separate question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, their type is "Starter"

First off, the full text for *Animal Man* is as follows:

> **+2 Power** and choose a card type. Reveal the top card of your deck. If it has that card type, draw it.

The key phrase here is "card type". Page 2 of the rulebook talks about types of cards and shows that the text in the colored bar below the picture is the card type.

[image]

As we can see, both *Punch* and *Vulnerability* have a card type of "Starter". This is corroborated by the explicit listing of the card types at the bottom of the page:

> The different card types that you can play are: Starter, Villain, Location, Hero, Super Power, and Equipment. Weakness cards have no card type.

Comment: Forgot to add this to question: Can Kicks be added to the Line Up? (the villain whose attack say to add a card with cost 1 or more from hand to lineup)

Comment: @Javier See my comment below the question. On this site, each question needs to be its own thread. I'd be happy to help answer that if it's asked as a separate question. Also, don't forget to accept this answer (click the check box) if it answers your question.